# Boost metaparse how to return custom types

Tags: parsing, boost, boost-mpl

I'm trying to create a simple parser with metaparse to demonstrate how I can return my own custom types.

If I had a custom type `ValNum`, how can I integrate this into a basic parser such that it is returned by the parser after matching a number? Apologies if this is trivial but I've been struggling to achieve this.

```
template<int Value>
struct ValNum {
    constexpr static int value = Value;
};
```

Comment: This really requires more code. MetaParse is highly specialistic, few people will know how to get started. Supplying a minimal self-contained example is good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return custom types by using the `transform` function along with a
[metafunction](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/metaparse/reference.html#metafunction).

Here's a really quick example of returning a custom type (butchering the `identity` metafunction class they gave in the link and a couple over examples I found in their offical GitHub)

```
// custom type here
template<int Value>
struct ValNum {
    constexpr static int value = Value;
};

struct identity
{
  template <class T>
  struct apply
  {
    // ValNum is my custom type
    using type = ValNum<T::type::value>; 
  };
  using type = identity;
};

typedef
  grammar<_STR("int_token")>
    ::import<_STR("int_token"), token<transform<int_, identity>>>::type
  expression;

typedef build_parser<entire_input<expression>> calculator_parser;

int main()
{

  // hello is now our custom ValNum type
  using hello = apply_wrap1<calculator_parser, _STR("13")>::type;

  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;

  cout << hello::value << endl;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.